# Error when decode AAC with avcodec_decode_audio4()

Tags: c, ffmpeg, decode, aac

I'm trying to decode AAC with FFmpeg native decoder and encountered an error

```
SSR is not implemeted. Update your FFmpeg version to newest from Git. If the      problem still occurs, it mean that your file has a feature which has not implemented.
```

Function *avcodec_decode_audio4()* return -1163346256. Is this because of FFmpeg version? I downloaded shared and dev version from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). Is this up to date?

Here is the source code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"

extern "C" 
{
#ifndef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#endif
#include <libavcodec\avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

// compatibility with newer API
#if LIBAVCODEC_VERSION_INT < AV_VERSION_INT(55,28,1)
#define av_frame_alloc avcodec_alloc_frame
#define av_frame_free avcodec_free_frame
#endif

#define AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE 20480
#define AUDIO_REFILL_THRESH 4096


static void audio_decode_example(const char *outfilename, const char *filename);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    audio_decode_example("D:\\sample.pcm","D:\\sample.m4a");
    getch();
    return 0;
}


/*
 * Audio decoding.
 */
static void audio_decode_example(const char *outfilename, const char *filename)
{
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVFormatContext   *pFormatCtx = NULL;
    AVCodecContext    *pCodecCtxOrig = NULL;
    AVCodecContext * pCodecCtx= NULL;
    int len;
    FILE *f, *outfile;
    uint8_t inbuf[AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];
    AVPacket avpkt;
    AVFrame *decoded_frame = NULL;


    av_register_all();

    av_init_packet(&avpkt);

    printf("Decode audio file %s to %s\n", filename, outfilename);

    // Open file to get format context
    if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, filename, NULL, NULL)!=0){
        printf("Couldn't open file");
        return; // Couldn't open file
    }

    // Retrieve stream information
    if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL)<0){
        printf("Couldn't find stream information");
        return; // Couldn't find stream information
    }

    // Dump information about file onto standard error
    av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, filename, 0);

    // Find the first audio stream
    int audioStream = -1;
    int i =0;
    for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
        if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            audioStream=i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(audioStream==-1) {
        printf("Didn't find a audio stream");
        return; // Didn't find a audio stream
    }

    // Get a pointer to the codec context for the audio stream
    pCodecCtxOrig=pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream]->codec;

    // Find the decoder for the audio stream
    codec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtxOrig->codec_id);
    if(codec==NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        return; // Codec not found
    }

    pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!pCodecCtx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate audio codec context\n");
        return;
    }

    if(avcodec_copy_context(pCodecCtx, pCodecCtxOrig) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't copy codec context");
        return; // Error copying codec context
    }


    /* open it */
    if (avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        return;
    }

    f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
        return;
    }
    outfile = fopen(outfilename, "wb");
    if (!outfile) {
        av_free(pCodecCtx);
        return;
    }

    /* decode until eof */
    avpkt.data = inbuf;
    avpkt.size = fread(inbuf, 1, AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE, f);

    while (avpkt.size > 0) {
        int i, ch;
        int got_frame = 0;

        if (!decoded_frame) {
            if (!(decoded_frame = av_frame_alloc())) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate audio frame\n");
                return;
            }
        }

        len = avcodec_decode_audio4(pCodecCtx, decoded_frame, &got_frame, &avpkt);
        if (len < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while decoding. len = %d \n",len);
            return;
        }
        if (got_frame) {
            /* if a frame has been decoded, output it */
            int data_size = av_get_bytes_per_sample(pCodecCtx->sample_fmt);
            if (data_size < 0) {
                /* This should not occur, checking just for paranoia */
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to calculate data size\n");
                return;
            }
            for (i=0; i < decoded_frame->nb_samples; i++)
                for (ch=0; ch < pCodecCtx->channels; ch++)
                    fwrite(decoded_frame->data[ch] + data_size*i, 1, data_size, outfile);
        }
        avpkt.size -= len;
        avpkt.data += len;
        avpkt.dts =
        avpkt.pts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;
        if (avpkt.size < AUDIO_REFILL_THRESH) {
            /* Refill the input buffer, to avoid trying to decode
             * incomplete frames. Instead of this, one could also use
             * a parser, or use a proper container format through
             * libavformat. */
            memmove(inbuf, avpkt.data, avpkt.size);
            avpkt.data = inbuf;
            len = fread(avpkt.data + avpkt.size, 1,
                        AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE - avpkt.size, f);
            if (len > 0)
                avpkt.size += len;
        }
    }

    fclose(outfile);
    fclose(f);

    avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);
    av_free(pCodecCtx);
    av_frame_free(&decoded_frame);
}
```

I have also read this question: [How to decode AAC using avcodec_decode_audio4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033100/how-to-decode-aac-using-avcodec-decode-audio4) but no solution is provided.

Comment: Your audio input file uses a feature that the decoder does not yet support. I'd recommend to open a bug report and upload a sample of your file so it can be implemented (https://www.ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html). Where did you get this file/data/stream from?

Comment: Does SSR here mean AAC SSR profile? I used a file encode with AAC LC profile. I can't upload the file right now because it's in other computer. I also try with the mp2 (got return -1163346256) from here: http://www.squee.eclipse.co.uk/samples/ and some mp3 in my computer (got error header missing). Is there something wrong with the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> f = fopen(filename, "rb");
> if (!f) {
>     fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
>     return;
> }
> outfile = fopen(outfilename, "wb");
> if (!outfile) {
>     av_free(pCodecCtx);
>     return;
> }
>
> /* decode until eof */
> avpkt.data = inbuf;
> avpkt.size = fread(inbuf, 1, AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE, f);
>
> while (avpkt.size > 0) {
>     int i, ch;
>     int got_frame = 0;
> ```

Yeah, that's not going to work. You can't dump raw bytes from some random muxing format (potentially mp4) into a decoder and expect it to work. Use [av_read_frame](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga4fdb3084415a82e3810de6ee60e46a61)() to read individual audio packets from the muxing format, and feed the resulting AVPacket into the decoder using avcodec_decode_audio4(). See e.g. the [dranger api tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html). I know api-example.c uses the above code, but that unfortunately only works for a very limited subset of cases. Also see the detailed description in the [API docs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#details).

Comment: Thank you, I replace the fread function with av_read_frame() and It's work now. I have some more questions, I would be grateful if you could give me some advices. The input of av_read_frame() is AVFormatContext so what if I have more than one stream?  How can I set pcm type (s16le, f32be etc) for the output file .pcm. I try set AVCodecContext->sample_fmt but it got error.

Comment: Each stream (AVStream) in the same file (AVFormatContext) will set AVPacket.stream_index to the index of that AVStream inside the AVFormatContext->streams[] array. You can't set pcm_type, each native decoder has one output type and that's what you get. If you want to convert from native output type to something else, use libswresample to do format (and samplerate, and channel) conversion.